# Why won't the assigned font family load on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-face, webfonts

I have been dealing with this issue all day and I can't seem to find a solution at all to why this is happening. The font family that I'm trying to set for the text on my website won't load on any other device **at all**, no matter what I try to do. It only loads on PC but nothing else that I test the site on. It's seriously annoying me.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap");

@font-face {
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
src: url("fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.eot");
src: url("fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
     url("fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
     url("fonts/roboto-v20-latin-regular.woff") format("woff"),
     url("fonts/roboto-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto Light", sans-serif;
  src: url("fonts/Lightversion/Roboto-Light.eot");
  src: url("fonts/Lightversion/Roboto-Light.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("fonts/Lightversion/Roboto-Light.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("fonts/Lightversion/Roboto-Light.woff") format("woff");
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Roboto Light", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(../images/playstation-pattern.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.welcome {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  color: #404040;
  font-family: "Roboto Light", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: normal;
}

.inner-welcome {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.welcome h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto Light", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.welcome p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #404040;
}

a:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.75);
  color: #404040;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #404040;
}

i {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Why are you importing Roboto from Google *and* locally?

Comment: I'm not sure. Originally I didn't use `@import`, I only tried importing the font locally and then ran a localhost on my network to test the webpage on my iPhone. The font still wasn't loading, so I tried using both `@import` (from Google) and `@font-face` (from a local font folder). Currently, the issue is still there.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Taken from the google fonts site, add the following to the head of your document:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
</style>
```

and then add the following in your stylesheet:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

This *should* take care of the Roboto Font.

In terms of the Light font, confirm that the fonts are in the */fonts/* folder in your site directory. It looks like it's using a fallback.

Comment: I actually tried that method before. I didn't realize I was supposed to place that into the head of the document. The fonts are showing up now... thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.

The `Roboto` don't family isn't imported properly. Here you have tried to import locally and remotely using Google font api. It is wrong. You should follow only one method of above.
The reason for issue occurs in all other devices and not in PC is that `Roboto` font has been installed to the PC. As other devices couldn't find `Roboto` font internally, they are trying to load that fallback font called `sans serif`.

Remove that import css rule and try to link Google font inside `header` tag of your `index.html` as shown below

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap">
```